# LocalDB missing from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-express, localdb

I am trying to add a local database to my project but there doesn't seem to be such an option.

[image]

Comment: LocalDB is a connection string, not an item that you add.

Comment: So if i want a database in order to save data that the user fills in the forms how do i do it? Sorry but i am a novice as you can already tell

Comment: `LocalDB` is a specific version of [SQL Server **Express**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) which you might need to download and install separately

Comment: Tried to install that earlier but it gave me an error while downloading setup files will try again though tnx

Comment: here it goes again http://prnt.sc/d9o6vy

Answer (score 3):

The "Local Database" template has been removed from VS 2015 - suggest you find a tutorial on MSDN that relates to VS 2015. You can use Service Based database instead, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download it from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

after installation restart your visual studio and you can find the option right there now.

**Or better you reinstall the latest stable version of VS-2015 again.**

Comment: I tried downloading this earlier and it got an error, then i tried again with download now install later and it got stuck at the end but i will try it again i guess if that dosent work i will reinstall VS

Comment: Yes try re- installing VS, but be sure to remove all the previous files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Framework Code First or Entity Framework Model First approach. If you are a novice, first google some tutorials about it :)

Comment: Well i am reading headfirst C# right now and i have seen other tutorials as well and they all do the same, add-newitem-localdatabase :/

Comment: I don't know which tutorials you are watching, but you can add ADO.NET Entity Data Model and then choose Model First approach